# Ruby: An Win32API call to Winsock2 ioctlsocket fails, bad address?

Tags: ruby, winapi, winsock, nonblocking

I want to change my Winsock2 socket from blocking to non-blocking one.
And I know that this can be achieved by calling the "ioctlsocket" function in ws2_32.dll library.
But my implementation fails to do its purpose with a return value of -1, which indicates a socket error.
I tried retrieving the error code by calling WSAGetLastError, and it returns 10014, which I guess has something to do with invalid pointer.
What could be my fault in this case?
I suppose it is my incorrectly declaring or passing values over to the API function, but I couldn't figure it out why.
Or anybody can suggest an alternative way to make a socket non-blocking?

(For some reasons, I cannot use Ruby's socket classes.)

Here is my code(@fd is the descriptor to my socket):

proc = Win32API.new("ws2_32", "ioctlsocket", "plp", "l")
ret = proc.call(@fd, 0x8004667E, 1)  # FIONBIO
p ret
=> -1

Comment: Since I posted this on the mobile site, all returns seem to be ignored, making it harder to look at.. I'm sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, that I need to "pack" the last argument in an array.
I thought that is only the case for C-style structs, but it somehow did the trick.
Now the socket successfully enters nonblocking mode.

The working code looks like this:

proc.call(@fd, 0x8004667E, [1].pack("l")) # FIONBIO

I don't think anybody would need this, though.
Ruby's own socket implementation is powerful yet much simpler than having to write a socket wrapper by oneself.

Answer (score 1):

The last parameter is crashing you:

`proc = Win32API.new("ws2_32", "ioctlsocket", "plp", "l") ret = proc.call(@fd, 0x8004667E, 1) # FIONBIO p ret => -1`

[`ioctlsocket()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738573%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)'s last parameter is a **pointer** to a long, not a long (the [10014 return code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is WSAEFAULT which means basically that it crashed trying to dereference that parameter). I don't know enough Ruby to tell you how to form a pointer to a long to pass instead, but hopefully this is enough to get you going.

Comment: I see where the problem is. But I'm still unclear about the way Ruby deals with pointers. As far as I know, every integer, long, or any other data types in Ruby are "objects." And note that I used "p" for the last parameter for export ("plp"), which stands for "pointer." So I am passing 1, a Fixnum object, for the last parameter of the function ioctlsocket. Then isn't it the address of the object which should be passed to the function? Is pointers in C and Ruby even compatible with each other?

Comment: for other functions that I implemented, passing string values through "p" parameters didn't matter at all. That's my assumption that it would be the same in other classes also. Or is there a Ruby way to get the address of an object?

Comment: Actually I have no idea. Googling around indicates it's not possible to get the actual address. There's probably a way to make this work but all I know about Ruby is its name...

Comment: @HerrJoebob +1, just for 'all I know about Ruby is its name' - sounds good, keep it up :)

Comment: I just managed to figure it out by myself. Thanks anyway for the idea. :)

Comment: You could always add an answer to your own question and mark that as the solution, in case somebody else runs into it.